# Determine all theta satisfying an expression

Tags: abstract-algebra, formal-proofs

For what values of θ
does the following equation hold
$$∏^{100}_{k=1} [\cos (kθ)+ i \sin (kθ)] = 1.$$

We can assume $∑^n_{i=1} i =\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ for all natural numbers $n$.

Answer (score 0):

By Euler's formula, $\displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^{100}e^{ik\theta} = 1 \rightarrow e^{i\theta+2i\theta+\cdots+100i\theta} = 1 = e$. Thus, $e^{5050i\theta} = 1 \rightarrow 5050\theta = 360^\circ\pi k$ and $\theta = \dfrac{36^\circ}{505}k$.

Comment: Just because $e^{i \phi} = 1$ doesn't mean $\phi = 0$.  $\phi$ could also be any integer multiple of $2 \pi i$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but when you say 5050θ=360∘πk what does that mean?

Is it that 5050 * θ = 2πk ?

Comment: Yes, but $\theta$ is usually regarded to deal with degrees, not radians.